# CSV size limit when using TABCMD and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, cmd, tableau-api

When I trying export datatable in `.csv` file and run my script it appears that the file can't download because his size more 50MB. When the file size is 49MB, my script runs again, and downloads the wrong version.

I'm using Powershell encryption

How can I get rid of this limitation of 50MB?

```
######################################
# User supplied variables
$serverURL = "MY SERVER"
$siteID = "MY SITE" # Leave siteID blank for Default site 
$tabcmdPath = "TAB CMD SERVER PATH"

# Pull credentials from encrypted files
$getPassword = Get-Content $(Join-Path -Path (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -ChildPath "encrypted.password") | ConvertTo-SecureString
$username = Get-Content $(Join-Path -Path (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -ChildPath "username")
$newCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $getPassword)
$password = $newCreds.GetNetworkCredential().password

## MAIN SCRIPT ##
# Login via TabCMD 
if ($siteID -eq "")
{
    & $(Join-Path -Path $tabcmdPath -ChildPath "tabcmd.exe") login -s $serverURL -u $username -p $password
}
else
{
    & $(Join-Path -Path $tabcmdPath -ChildPath "tabcmd.exe") login -s $serverURL -t $siteID -u $username -p $password
}

# Run whatever TabCMD commands you need
& $(Join-Path -Path $tabcmdPath -ChildPath "tabcmd.exe") export "PATH TO MY DASH" --csv -f "PATH TO CSV.csv"

# Log out via TabCMD
& $(Join-Path -Path $tabcmdPath -ChildPath "tabcmd.exe") logout
```

And then I run this file `Powershell.exe -File D:\path\Desktop\encrypt\encrypt-playbook.ps1` via `cmd.exe`

Comment: Please add the actual error message. Is the file size issue from `tabcmd.exe export` or from `encrypt-playbook.ps1`? If the issue is with the `.ps1` script, then add what that script is doing to your question instead.

Comment: [Looks like the Tableau frontend web server might have a hard 50MB limit for file transfers](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000aWg26/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-size-limit-for-a-workbook-above-50-mb) - you should probably contact Tableau Support and get them to confirm and/or provide a workaround

Comment: Why not export the data from the database rather than Tableau ? What's the benefit of using Tableau in this example ?